# SIP registration - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sip

Hi I want to develop an application to call and answer calls, with the code below I get the answer "SipManager is closed" and the Toast "Not registered".

I don't get any exception and the Toast in "setRegistrationListener" were never launched.

What is wrong? What is the problem?

```
 private void inicializarPerfilLocal(){
        if(mSipManager == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al iniciar administrador SIP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return;
        }
    String username = COUNTRYCODE+PHONE_NUMBER;
    String domain = "xx.yy.zz";
    String password = "ABCABCABC";

    try{
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        builder.setAuthUserName(username+"@"+domain);
        builder.setOutboundProxy("255.255.255.0");
        builder.setProfileName(username + "@" + domain );
        builder.setDisplayName("Test");
        builder.setProtocol("TCP");
        builder.setAutoRegistration(true);

        mSipProfile = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pi, null);

        if (mSipManager.isOpened(mSipProfile.getUriString())){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Administrador abierto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Administrador cerrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registrando...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registrado",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                             String errorMessage) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en registro errorCode :: "+errorMessage,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        if (mSipManager.isRegistered(mSipProfile.getUriString())){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }catch(ParseException pe){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Excepcion de parseo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(SipException se){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Excepcion SIP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following things
1. Your network conectivity is fine i.e. IP and port no are openend. To check this just have a softphone installed and get it registered.

2. In your code i could see you are using TCP as an protocol for SIP register. Please confirm normally port 5060 are open for UDP
   Following is code which you might have to think about 
   builder.setProtocol("TCP");

Comment: Hi Ravi! about your recomendations, the IP and port are opened because I configure the service with CSIPSimple and it works. About second recommendation, I changed to "UDP" and now I have "SipManager is open" but not registered. I get an "-9" (RegistrationFailed -9 :: 0) and "-4" (RegistrationFailed -4 :: registration not running) error in the log.

Comment: Please check logs through tcpdump & what kind of error you are getting on tcpdump. Hopefully it must be CSIPSimple accepts all kinds of headers but your App doesn't